# ¿Como hacer funcionar el push e imprimir con arreglos una Pila?

Tags: c++, array, pilas, push

Resulta que quiero hacer pilas con arreglos, y quiero hacer funcionar el push y el imprimir, pero me lo imprime con errores.

¿Que correciones puedo hacer? si es posible, el pop tambien lo quiero hacer, mas no tengo idea como hacerlo.

Codigo:

Pilas.h

```
#pragma once
#define LongitudMaxima 6
class Pilas
{
private:
    int nValor,Tope, nPila[LongitudMaxima];
public:
    Pilas();
    ~Pilas();
    bool EstaVacia();
    bool EstaLlena();
    bool push(int nValor);
    void imprimir();
};
```

Pilas.ccp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Pilas.h"


Pilas::Pilas()
{
    Tope = -1;
    for (int nIndex = 0; nIndex < 6; nIndex++)
    {
        nPila[nIndex] = 0;
    }
}


Pilas::~Pilas()
{
}

bool Pilas::EstaVacia()
{
    return Tope == -1;
}

bool Pilas::EstaLlena()
{
    return Tope = nPila[LongitudMaxima];
}

bool Pilas::push(int nValor)
{
    bool bAllOk = false;
    if (!EstaLlena())
    {
        if (EstaVacia())
        {
            return true;
            Tope = 0;
            nPila[0] = nValor;

        }
        else
        {
            for (int nIndex = 1; nIndex < LongitudMaxima; nIndex++)
            {
                cout << "LA PILA ESTA LLENA..." << endl;
            }

        }
    }
}

void Pilas::imprimir()
{
        cout << "LA PILA es: " << push(nValor)<< endl;
}
```

main.cpp: define el punto de entrada de la aplicación de consola.

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int main()
{
    Pilas A;
    A.imprimir();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tienes muchos errores de concepto y de lógica en tu programa. La función `imprimir` ni siquiera recorre los elementos ¡llama a `push`! También llamas a `imprimir` en `main` sin haber añadido datos a la pila, así que no debería tener nada a imprimir. Por favor: ponnos un ejemplo de los datos que introduces y los datos que recibes... en otras palabras: detalla más lo que tú consideras "*me lo imprime con errores*".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías usar `LongitudMaxima` en lugar de `6` en `Pilas::Pilas()`.

`EstaLlena` tiene varios problemas. Tratas de leer `nPila[LongitudMaxima]`. Recuerda que `LongitudMaxima` es **6**, y tu array tiene elementos **del 0 al 5**. Estás leyendo memoria que no te pertenece, podría existir cualquier cosa ahí.

Supongo que `Tope` va aumentando cada vez que haces `push` de un elemento a la pila y guarda su posición en el array, aunque no veo esa funcionalidad en `Pilas::push` todavía.

Pero bueno, en `Pilas::EstaLlena` supongo que la intención es tratar de comparar `Tope` con la posición del último elemento posible(`LongitudMaxima-1`), pero en lugar de eso tomas el **valor** del último elemento del array(y mal porque es un elemento fuera del array), y ese valor se lo asignas a `Tope`, y luego el nuevo valor asignado de `Tope` se convierte en el valor de retorno de la función con el `return`.

Creo que lo que quisiste hacer era algo como: `return Tope == LongitudMaxima-1;`

Al método `push` le falta mucho todavía.